# GUID field in EditForm

Tags: edit, guid

I have some GUID fields in a custom list. I've created a webpart to manage that list. By code I can edit the content of these fields successfully (with JSOM).

However, I can't add the values for these fields when I edit the list item using the SharePoint UI (EditForm.aspx). These fields don't show any control like a textbox or dropdownlist for example. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Sure, in my Elements.xml file I have the following field:  <!-- language: c# --><Field ID={...} Name="ListGUID" DisplayName="GUID de lista" Type="Guid" Required="FALSE" Group="My custom columns">  </Field>